# How to replace a string with the array and index of an array as a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider

```
var arr = ["a","b","c"];
var string = "Hello {1} is a friend of {2} and {3}";
```

so replacing `{1}` with `"a"`, `{2}` with `"b"`, and `{3}` with `"c"`

How do we do using JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with array reduction and string replacement.

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c"];
var s = "Hello {1} is a friend of {2} and {3}";

var result = arr.reduce((str, replacement, idx) => {
  return str.replace(`{${idx + 1}}`, replacement)
}, s);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [template strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) in ES6.

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const string = `Hello ${arr[0]} is a friend of ${arr[1]} and ${arr[2]}`;
```

---

Addind some [destructuring](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html)

```
const [
  a,
  b
  c,
] = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const string = `Hello ${a} is a friend of ${b} and ${c}`;
```

---

**@EDIT in ES5, the good old**

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var string = 'Hello ' + arr[0] + ' is a friend of ' + arr[1] + ' and ' + arr[2];
```

[image]

Comment: i want to write it in plain JS not he es6

Comment: @PramodMg ES6 is plain JS

Comment: i meant in es5 @nem035

Comment: @PramodMg I have added a soluce in es5

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regex and the string `.replace` method:

```js
var arr = ["a","b","c"];
var str = "Hello {1} is a friend of {2} and {3}"

var newstr = str.replace(/\{(\d)\}/gm, (_m, i) => {
  const index = Number(i) - 1;
  return arr[index]
});

console.log(newstr)
```